# Nodeunit coffeescript test file is not picked up by npm test

Tags: unit-testing, coffeescript, npm, nodeunit

I have this in `./package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "nodeunit test"
}
```

and this file `./test/log.coffee`

```
module.exports =
    'Test logging': (test) ->
        test.expect(1)
        console.log("yeah")
        test.ok(true)
        test.done()
```

When I execute `npm test` I get this: **OK: 0 assertions (1ms)**

However it **runs fine when I try these**:

- Execute `nodeunit test` directly.
- Convert `./test/log.coffee` to Javascript `./test/log.js` and execute `npm test`

What can I do to make my `npm test` to pick up the coffeescript test file?